# BeautifulSoup Keep some text, but remove the rest of the tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working with a bot that scrapes data from a forum. I have this here to work with:

```
<description><![CDATA[ <p>This is a test post with a few emotes <img src="https://sjc5.discourse-cdn.com/try/images/emoji/twitter/grin.png?v=9" title=":grin:" class="emoji" alt=":grin:"> <img src="https://sjc5.discourse-cdn.com/try/images/emoji/twitter/heart.png?v=9" title=":heart:" class="emoji" alt=":heart:"></p> ]]></description>
```

From this I want to get

`This is a test post with a few emotes :grin: :heart:`

How would I go about doing that? I also want to be able to do this if the emote is in the middle of the text as well.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried anything? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, CData

txt = '''<description><![CDATA[ <p>This is a test post with a few emotes <img src="https://sjc5.discourse-cdn.com/try/images/emoji/twitter/grin.png?v=9" title=":grin:" class="emoji" alt=":grin:"> <img src="https://sjc5.discourse-cdn.com/try/images/emoji/twitter/heart.png?v=9" title=":heart:" class="emoji" alt=":heart:"></p> ]]></description>'''

# load main soup:
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# find CDATA inside <description>, make new soup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('description').find(text=lambda t: isinstance(t, CData)), 'html.parser')

# replace <img> with their alt=...
for img in soup2.select('img'):
    img.replace_with(img['alt'])

# print text
print(soup2.p.text)
```

Prints:

```
This is a test post with a few emotes :grin: :heart:
```